# How can i filter data in continuos refreshing table?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, flask

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgGK6.gif

I have a table continuous refreshing table by data from that comes tcp socket. I want to filter this table. I used jQuery but when i filtered table after reload table.

I just want the filtered data to be refreshed. But jQuery refreshing all. How can I prevent this?

Here is my HTML markup:

```
<div class="card-body">
          <div>
            <div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">
              <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  id="myInput"
                  name="search"
                  onkeyup="myFunction()"
                  placeholder="Search for names.."
                />
                <tr class="odd gradeX">
                  <td>
                    <table
                      class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
                      id="refresh"
                    ></table>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <table
                      class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-responsive"
                      id="inputs"
                    ></table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="/static/javascripts/searchBlocks.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    const refreshData = window.setInterval(function () {
      loadNewData();
    }, 1000);
    const buttonsAndIntervals = setInterval(function () {
      reload();
    }, 5000);
    function loadNewData() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/webguivalue",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
          $(refresh).replaceWith(data);
        },
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to understand why this is happening,
it happens because you are replacing the value of the entire table each time you load a new data, the fix is also simple
on the part where you are calling
`$(refresh).replaceWith(data);`

add another line to call your function which you already using to filter the table:
`myFunction()`

so the final call after you do the ajax is:

```
    $(refresh).replaceWith(data); 
    myFunction();
```